# segmentation fault / malloc error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

EDIT: PROBLEM NOW SOLVED, THANKS ALL

So I'm writing a code for my final piece of C coursework. I've written a function FastDFS which carries out a Fourier Transform. The following code is supposed to time this process for different input sizes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

void FastDFS(complex double *, complex double *, complex double *, complex double *, int, int);
void print_complex_vector(complex double *, int);
void free_complex_vector(complex double *);
complex double *make_complex_vector(int);
complex double *MakeWpowers(int);

int main(void)
{
    int i,N, operations_required;
    int index_counter = 1;
    double initial_time, final_time, time_taken, mega_flops_rate;

    complex double *mega_flops_vector = make_complex_vector(21);

    for(N = 2; N <= pow(2,20); N = N * 2)
    {
        complex double *Wp = MakeWpowers(N);
        complex double *y = make_complex_vector(N);
        complex double *x = make_complex_vector(N);
        complex double *w = make_complex_vector(N);

        printf("N = %d\n",N);

        operations_required = 1024;

        for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        {
            y[i] = i;
        }

        initial_time = clock();
        FastDFS(x,y,w,Wp,N,1);
        final_time = clock();

        time_taken = (final_time - initial_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        mega_flops_rate = operations_required / (time_taken * pow(10,6));

        free(Wp);
        free(y);
        free(x);
        free(w);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

The code has been simplified slightly from the original, but contains the same error. At some stage either the error "timings.out(49621,0x7fff7e684300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f81ca80c208: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed."  is returned or Segmentation Fault:11. Where the program crashes varies on different runs, but never gets part N = 8192.

I've written a main function to test the code and don't encounter these errors. The main uses the same functions (make_complex_vector etc). A difference I can see is that I don't free any pointers in the main as I only test it for one value of N at a time, but I don't see how this could cause it to crash? I can run the code for much greater values of N than this in the main.

Can anyone see something obviously wrong here? Many thanks

Comment: What line number is given for the error?

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating from 1 -> N and assigning to `y`.  In C, arrays are 0-indexed. For example, if you create an array of size 5, the elements are numbered like so:

`[a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]]` (5 elements, numbered 0-4)

So instead of

```
for(i = 1; i <= N; i++)
```

what you really want is

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
```

Otherwise, you are going to write past the end of the allocated memory. If you want the first element of the vector to be 1, write something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    y[i] = i + 1;
}
```

(I am assuming that `make_complex_vector(N)` allocates an array of size `N`).

Comment: unfortunately this isn't the issue. You're right, my function to make the vector used to assign N+1 spaces so I could pretend that the array ran from 1 to N. On applying this change I do seem to no longer get the malloc error, but the Seg fault remains

Comment: @Conor Perhaps we can see your `make_complex_vector` function as well as the other functions that are declared but not defined in the code that you have provided?

Comment: hey man thanks for your help. I was just about to post these functions when I realised that the mistake is just that w requires more space then the others and I hadn't given it enough. Problem solved, sorry for being such a noob, thanks for your time :) @Daniel

Comment: Go ahead and answer as such and close the thread then, when you get a chance.

Comment: @Conor No problem. Just as a side-point, allocating N+1 elements for an array and not using position 0 is _very_ non-colloquial for C.  Most C programmers would be extremely confused to see a loop going from 1 and with a <= N condition. For the sake of making your code understandable, don't do that.